# Any Good IDEs out there?

Tags: text-editor, ide, programming

Can someone list a few good IDEs? I am looking for an IDE that supports many languages mainly Java, HTML, JavaScript, C# and C++. I already use all the JetBrains products and Visual Studio. I am just wondering if anyone knows any other very good IDEs.
And I am on currently on windows so please keep that in mind.

Comment: Do your requirements include Android development?

Comment: The JetBrains products are generally regarded as the best in the business. Edit your Question to describe exactly what else you are looking for, be specific about what is lacking.

Comment: @karel No it is not for android development

Comment: Did you look at https://netbeans.org/ and https://eclipse.org/ide/ bot are free and widely used in industry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Atom on my Mac but it runs on Windows too. Its mainly an editor but has many plugins to make it run like an IDE. I've used it mainly for Python and HTML. It has plugins I think for all the languages you listed. Atom and all plugins are free. It is actively under development so upgrades come often. Most plugins are developed by users so there is something for almost everyone.

Comment: No problem... you're welcome.  Hope it works for you as well as it did for me.

Answer (score 1):

One of the best these days is [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) (not to be confused with Visual Studio). VS Code is in many ways like Atom: both are built on the Electron platform (Chromium and Node.js); both come with editing support for many languages, including all the ones you listed; both come with some IDE features included and have an ecosystem of plugins to extend functionality.

VS Code and Atom are both good, and each has some advantages over the other. VS Code's advantages include being faster and having more IDE features right out of the box.